# Почему не запускается программа?

Tags: android-sdk, eclipse

При запуске программы Eclipse SDK появляется окно с ошибкой запуска программы Android SDK Manager. Почему не получается запуск?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это предупреждение, ошибки пока нет.

Comment: так как запустить Android SDK